# Using different templates in different project groups in NetBeans

Tags: templates, netbeans

I am working on two entirely separate Java products in NetBeans. I have them set up as separate project groups.

I want to change the templates for the second product so that it uses its product name, website etc. But if I do this, I find that the change affects the first product too. Templates appear to be global.

Is there a way around this? A way to make each project group use its own separate templates?

Answer (score 0):

for the maven base project you can specify license in the pom.xml:

```
<properties> 
  <netbeans.hint.license>mylicense</netbeans.hint.license>
</properties>
```

according to some posts you can specify other properties in the *nbproject/project.properties*, but seems this solution only possible for ant based projects